# How can I create a command that deletes the first x letters in each word of a string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I need to delete the first letters of each word of a string. I know that by using something like

```
st =  "testing"
st = st[3:]
```

I can delete the first 3 letters from that word.
I need to do this for many words in the same string now.
For example if I get

```
"hello this is a test"
```

I need to delete the first 2 letters (chose 2 randomly) from that word, but only if the lenght of that word is >=2.
the output of this example should be:

```
llo is  a st
```

(note that "is" got deleted because it has a lenght of 2 letters)

Comment: `' '.join([s[2:] for s in st.split()])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that a word is any sequence that does not contain spaces:

1. Split the text into words
2. Use list comprehension to modify the words that qualify
3. Join the results

If by "word" you mean *real* English words (that do not include punctuation, etc.), then use `nltk.word_tokenize(st)` instead of `st.split()`.

```
" ".join([(word[2:] if len(word) >= 2 else word) for word in st.split()])
#'llo is  a st'
```

Comment: what a nice snippet

Comment: Remember about `or`

Comment: @U9-Forward I feel that the if expression is more clear.

Comment: @DYZ I support you, whatever you say, i don't know a everything :-)

Comment: `nltk.word_tokenize` is a nice touch.

Answer (score 0):

Direct can do:

```
' '.join([s[2:] for s in st.split()])
```

But wanted to keep characters less than length of two:

```
' '.join([s[2:] or s for s in st.split()])
```

Use `or` because takes which that's True, `''` or `'a'` will choose `'a'`